# Firebase and Angularjs Scope array of objects undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, firebase, angularjs-scope

I am trying to display objects using angularjs. But in the html it appears as undefined.

```
app1.controller('ctrl1' , function($scope){ 
  categories = [];
  var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Categories/');
  dbRef.once('value', snap => {

    snap.forEach(function(childSnap) {
      //CATEGORY MODEL
       var category = {
            name : "",
            id  : "",

            subCategories: {
              name: "",
              id: ""
            }

        };
      category.id = childSnap.val().id
      category.name = childSnap.val().name
      category.subCategories = childSnap.val().subCategories
      categories.push(category)
    })

  }).then(() => {
    $scope.allcats = categories;
  });
});
```

And the html

```
 <div id="nav-aside " class="nav" ng-controller="ctrl1">
              {{allcats}}
            <ul class="nav-aside-list" ng-repeat="categories in allcats">
              <li><span></span><a href="#">{{categories.name}}</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

This doesnt work.  Anyone who can help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why you are using categories to push why not directly $scope.allcats?

Comment: @GauravSrivastava Anyway, nothing is displayed. i tried :(

Comment: do console log right below categories.push to see if any data is coming

Comment: @GauravSrivastava yes, data is coming. I am guessing this is a asynchronous problem? isnt it?

Comment: yest, let me add an answer based on async problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
app1.controller('ctrl1' , function($scope){ 
      $scope.allcats = [];
      var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Categories/');
      dbRef.once('value', snap => {

        snap.forEach(function(childSnap) {
          //CATEGORY MODEL
           var category = {
                name : "",
                id  : "",

                subCategories: {
                  name: "",
                  id: ""
                }

            };
          category.id = childSnap.val().id
          category.name = childSnap.val().name
          category.subCategories = childSnap.val().subCategories
          $scope.allcats.push(category);
          $scope.$apply();
        })

      }).then(() => {
        console.log($scope.allcats);
      });
    });
```

Comment: this works with the console. But in the html file no data is coming. Because html runs once and before the script, maybe

Comment: @AralbayIssatayev angular works on two way binding it should automatically reflect the changes in html template without doing anything. share some your config code may be you have angular setup wrong.

Comment: @AralbayIssatayev i edited my answer check if its working.

Comment: @AralbayIssatayev glad i could help